# How different, has closed VS has been closed?

Tags: passive-voice

1. The cafe has closed
2. The cafe has been closed

Two of the sentences have same meaning?

Comment: You would more frequently see usage 2 with a time qualifier: "The cafe has been closed **since 5 PM**," or "The cafe has been closed **all weekend**."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While they both *can* been the same thing, there can be differences in both in grammar and interpretation.

> The cafe has closed.

- Grammar: This is a simple statement of fact about the current state of the cafe.
- Interpretation: Generally, it would be interpreted as meaning that the cafe has closed *for the day*.

> The cafe has been closed.

- Grammar: Most often, this would represent the fact that the cafe has been closed *by* somebody. As opposed to the other sentence, it's not just a simple description but an indication of an action on somebody's part.
  It could also be considered not as an indication of action, but as way of expressing that it was closed at some point in the past (generally, for an extended period of time) and may or may not have reopened since.
- Interpretation: In addition to the interpretations possible from the grammar, it could also be taken to mean that the cafe *has gone out of business*.

---

Context is important in each of these sentences. While they *could* mean the same thing, they don't have to—and different interpretations are possible.